# Best way(s) of storing arrays of data for a website?

Tags: mysql, arrays, database, web

Sorry for the vague question, but I can only explain my question further by giving an example, of what I need the solution for.
In basketball, my friends and I take 20 shots at a time and record how many went in - I want to make a database to store each of these n/20 sets for each player in order to get averages. MySQL doesn't sound like the best solution as it can't store simple arrays.
Maybe I could store this data as a 2D array? eg.

```
stats = [ 
          [ ["me" , 12 , 14 , 8 , 19 , 13 , 10...] ],
          [ ["friend1" , 11 , 9 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 18...] ],
          [ ["friend2" , 17 , 9 , 18 , 14 , 17 , 17...] ]
        ]
```

I would like to keep each set of 20 as opposed to a running total percentage - how should I go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store it in separate tables, so you got:

```
Games - GameID, Date, NumberOfShots (so you're not fixed to 20), Etc
Players - PlayerID, Name, etc
Turns - TurnID, GameID, PlayerID, Score
```

From these you can easily aggregate per player, something like this.

Get avarage percentage per player over the last 30 days.

```
select
  p.PlayerID,
  p.Name
  AVG(p.Score / g.NumberOfShots) * 100 as Percentage
from
  Games g
  inner join Players p on p.GameID = g.GameID
  inner join Turns t on t.GameID = g.GameID and t.PlayerID = p.PlayerID
where
  g.Date > (sysdate() - 30)
group by 
  p.PlayerID,
  p.Name
```

Comment: That's a good idea! Would you say that similarly, I could make a table for each player, and have columns for each set of 20?

Comment: No. If you do that, then you would have to modify the tables everytime you want to add players or add a new match. With the structure I proposed, you can just create a match by inserting a record in Games. New players are inserted in the Players table. After the match, you insert the scores for each player in the Turns table. The same player can have turns in every game, so you just have to enter your and all your friends' names once. It's a tiny bit more complex due to one or a couple of tables, but once you've built it, you can use it without having to modify anything about your database.